# How to remove everything before first occurrence of a character in splunk

Tags: regex, replace, splunk

I have a string with certain formate

```
154787878_2582_test.txt.zip
```

I need to remove everything before first occurrence of `-` and remove  154787878_

I have tried

```
| eval txtFile=replace(mvindex(split(txtFile,"_"),0),"")
```

Please help

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/mD9JeR/6 -Is this ok ?  `(?:\d+)_(.*)`

Comment: as you have discovered, multivalue fields are immutable in Splunk. @Wiktor's answer is the right way to do this :)

Answer (score 4):

You may use

```
| eval txtFile = replace(txtFile,"^[^_]*_", "")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MCICbm/1)

The regex matches

- `^`  - start of string
- `[^_]*` - 0 or more chars other than `_`
- `_`  - an underscore.